# Nested <nested:equal> and <nested:write> in combination

Tags: java, jsp, struts, nested, equals

Basically, my question is simple but it requires someone that knows Struts 1.1 and is still alive.

What I try to build looks like this in Pseudo-Code:

```
IF element.method1 = true THEN
   IF element.method2 = true THEN
      COLOR.GREEN, PRINT element.prop1
   ELSE
      COLOR.RED, PRINT element.prop1
   END
ELSE
   COLOR.BLACK, PRINT element.prop1
END
```

The whole thing would happen inside a iteration. So here what is currently working but not yet the goal:

```xml
<nested:equal property="method1" value="true">
    <nested:write property="prop1" /> 
</nested:equal>

<nested:notEqual property="method1" value="true">
    <nested:write property="prop1" />
</nested:notEqual>
```

Now what really drives me crazy is that this works as well:

```xml
<nested:equal property="method1" value="true">
   <nested:equal property="method2" value="true">
   </nested:equal>                
</nested:equal>
                        
<nested:notEqual property="method1" value="true">
   <nested:write property="prop1" />
</nested:notEqual>
```

But whenever I insert something between the two inner `nested:equal` tags it wont compile.

So my final solution (see below) wont compile complaining `"Missing Endtag for nested:write."`

```xml
<nested:equal property="method1" value="true">

   <nested:equal property="method2" value="true">
           <nested:write property="element.prop1" />
   </nested:equal>   
                        
</nested:equal>
                        
<nested:notEqual property="method1" value="true">
    <nested:write property="element.prop1" />
</nested:notEqual>
```

After about 4 hours I still don't have a idea how I could manage this so any suggestions would be really appreciated and helps even 2 weeks after this post because my next step is to dig into Struts 1.1 Documentation.

Comment: Why do you use nested, are you disappointed with EL?

Comment: Not at all, unfortunately i am not allowed to use any "not yet used" technologies in the legacy system i am currently maintaining.

Comment: Well i checked the project files again. In each JSP there is the following line:

    <%@ include file="taglib.inc" %>

In the according file there is tags-tiles, tags-html, tags-logic, tags-bean and tags-nested included... am i right i can use EL now?

Comment: Use EL, it's easy, you don't have to write `nested` tags. You could also use JSTL instead of Struts1 tags, is a big step to migrate to newer version of Struts.

Comment: Also Struts 1.3.10 has support for EL and JSTL in their distro via the contrib.

Comment: Very many thanks for your comments! The problem is that the legacy system i am currently working with is not allowed to have any newer versions of Struts or anything else to be included since silly managers dont trust me to migrate to those technologies. I however managed to make it work

Comment: This is not a newer version, you can use JSTL in any version. Try it with your version and it should work. Anyway Struts 1.3 not much differ from 1.1 and it easily upgraded, this is not Struts 2. But if you decide to move to Struts 2 then JSTL would be a major cut off the time spent on migration.

Comment: Very many thanks for your input Roman C i have to admit i lost track on the whole Struts Projects and cant see those differences anymore. Since the company just wants me to accompany this legacy system on its way to EOL there wont be a migration to Struts 2.x.

Comment: JSTL is a technology recognized worldwide and is supported by your application without migration, I've used it a lot before Struts2. Currently I'm using OGNL for expression evaluation, however JSTL is still a valid choice but in Struts2 it looks like not much anticipated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the solution of Roman C worked perfectly, I also managed to get it together with the nested-tags.

I am unfortunately not allowed to post the original source, however this is what does & how it works right now:

```xml
<nested:form action="/someReq" styleClass="standard">
    <nested:present property="myBean.genList">

        <nested:iterate property="myBean.genList" indexId="index">

            <nested:equal property="method1" value="true">

                <nested:equal property="method2" value="true">
                    <strong class="green">
                        <nested:write property="prop1" />
                    </strong>
                </nested:equal>

                <nested:notEqual property="method2" value="true">
                    <strong class="red">
                        <nested:write property="prop1" />
                    </strong>
                </nested:notEqual>

            </nested:equal>

            <nested:notEqual property="method1" value="true">
                <nested:write property="prop1" />
            </nested:notEqual>

        </nested:iterate>

    </nested:present>
</nested:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

and the code will look like

```xml
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${element.method1 == true}"> 
    <c:choose> 
      <c:when test="${element.method2 == true}"> 
        <span style="color:green;"><c:out value="${element.prop1}/></span>
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
        <span style="color:red;"><c:out value="${element.prop1}/></span>
      </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <span style="color:black;"><c:out value="${element.prop1}/></span>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```